# How to use the === syntax from Specs2 in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest, specs2

I really like this syntax from Specs2 in order to test for equality:

1 + 1 === 2

instead of:

assert(1+1 == 2)

or the English-like synonims.

Can this syntax also be used in ScalaTest?

Here is the list of matchers that [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers) and [Specs2](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html) supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is described as supported in the docs of ScalaTest, so yes:

http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingEqualityWithMatchers

```
result should === (3)   // can customize equality and enforce type constraints
```

Comment: The syntax isn't so simple as with Specs2, but concise enough and readable.

Answer (score 0):

ScalaTest already supports this operator in trait `TripleEqualsSupport`

Here is the [scaladoc reference](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.0/index.html#org.scalactic.TripleEqualsSupport) for the current version

Comment: That's true, but there is no real gain in conciseness from assert(1+1 == 2) to assert(1+1 === 2)